# PHP todas las funciones y/o metodos de una clase tienen que retornar algo?

Tags: php, poo, php7, objeto

tengo esta clase :

```
<?php 

    /**
     * 
     */
    class miClase{
        //mis atributos
        public $resultado = 0;


        //mis metodos
        public function miMetodo($v1, $v2){

            $this->resultado = $v1 + $v2;

            return this->resultado;
        }

    }

 ?>
```

Siempre **tiene que retornar algo las funciones** ? Es decir, la funcion `miMetodo($v1,$v2)` podria dividirla en dos de la siguiente manera?

**metodo de asignacion**

```
public function metodoAsignar($v1, $v2){

   $this->resultado = $v1 + $v2;


 }
```

**metodo de retorno**

```
public function metodoRetorno(){

   return $this->resultado;


 }
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que estás preguntando ... ¿ Lo has probado ? ¿ No da el resultado que esperas ?

Comment: Bueno, mientras que lo pruebas y nos cuentas, voto por cerrarla porque *no está claro lo que se pregunta*.

Comment: Como indica @Trauma, no está claro lo que se pregunta. Si estás preguntando por el uso de `return`, basta que te pases por la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.returning-values.php) de PHP. Claramente indica: *"Los valores son devueltos usando la sentencia* ***opcional*** *return."*. Entonces la sentencia es *opcional*. Más adelante pone la siguiente nota: *Si se omite return, el valor devuelto será NULL.* ¿Es eso lo que preuguntas? Saludos

Comment: Disculpadme, eso era exactamente a lo que me referia. Que puede ser `void` o **retornar** , es que habia tuve un **malentendido** respecto a las funciones. Todo quedo solucionado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes dividirla en dos perfectamente, a partir de php 7.1 puedes poner esto para obligar a que el return este vacio.

```
public function metodoAsignar($v1, $v2) : void {
    return; // o se puede omitir
    return "Resultado"; // Daría error.
}
```

**Sin el : void**

```
public function metodoAsignar($v1, $v2) {
    $resultado=$v1+$v2;
    return "Resultado"; // se puede omitir y dejar solo la asignación.
}
```

Comment: Entonces, si no indico explicitamente que la función retorna `void` ... ¿ no se puede ? ¿ hay que retornar algo obligatoriamente ?

Comment: Si que se puede, el void es solo una restricción para que el return sea vacio (null tampoco vale).

Comment: Menos mal que has editado, porque tenía el `-1` cargado y listo para pulsar ... Personalmente, no soy partidario de responder a este tipo de preguntas, porque alienta a que continúen publicándose ... pero la respuesta es correcta, +1 :-)

Comment: La doy por valida, disculpad el malentendido que cree con esta pregunta. Indico correcta la pregunta y por cerrada la cuestion, pues es lo que mas se ajusta ami **demanda**. Gracias a todos

Comment: Me parece que tu primer ejemplo es incoherente y alienta a malas prácticas de programación. `void` significa *vacío* y tradicionalmente un método *void*  es un método que no devuelve nada, por tanto poner un `return` en él no tiene ninguna lógica. Si PHP 7 modificó muchas cosas fue precisamente para que no siguiéramos incurriendo en prácticas como estas.

Comment: Es para indicar que return tiene que estar vacío o directamente no ponerlo.