# PHP 7.2 me da null esta funcion

Tags: php, poo, php7

tengo la siguiente clase :

```
class claseHijo extends clasePadre{

    public function metodoHijo(){
        return self::metodoPadre();
    }

    public function saludar(){
        return "Hola, soy el hijo";
    }

    public function elegirSaludo(){
            self::saludar();
    }

}
```

y quiero llamar a la funcion `elegirSaludo()` por lo que hago lo siguiente:

```
$obj = new claseHijo();
echo "Mensaje = ".$obj->elegirSaludo();
```

Pero no me lo me sale nada, solo `Mensaje` . Por lo que **eche mano** a la variable `var_dump()` de **esa misma funcion** tal que asi:

```
echo var_dump($obj->elegirSaludo());
```

Esto me devuelve :

```
C:\directorios\herencia.php:36:null
```

Comment: Esta bien porque en la función `elegirSaludo` no estas retornando el valor. por lo que retornara `null`. Lo que debes hacer es un `return self::saludar();`

Comment: Tanto esta como la anterior podrían calificarse de *errores tipográficos*. Creo que deberías repasar un poco la sintaxis del lenguaje ... o al menos el capítulo de las clases. Con la **magnífica documentación en castellano** que tiene PHP ...

Comment: Hola, en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255531/php-todas-las-funciones-y-o-metodos-de-una-clase-tienen-que-retornar-algo#comment474306_255531) en tu pregunta anterior, trataba de aclararte precisamente ese punto. Al no usar la sentencia `return`, tu función ***siempre*** devolverá `null` (excepto en los casos que tu función sea `void`). Saludos

Comment: Perfecto, vi que era por la falta de un `return` en mi funcion. Fue un **error tipografico** exactamente.

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente por que tu método `elegirSaludo()` tiene por dentro una referencia a otro método dentro del mismo alcance de la clase que es `saludar()` pero en ningún momento lo estás retornando por eso no te devuelve nada.

Deberás agregar explícitamente un `return` a tu método para que devuelva lo que contiene

```
<?php

class clasePadre{
        public function metodoPadre(){
            return "Hola desde el padre";
        }

        public function saludar(){
            return "Hola, soy el padre";
        }
    }

class claseHijo extends clasePadre{

    public function metodoHijo(){
        return self::metodoPadre();
    }

    public function saludar(){
        return "Hola, soy el hijo";
    }

    public function elegirSaludo(){
            return self::saludar();
    }

}

$obj = new claseHijo();
echo "Mensaje = ".$obj->elegirSaludo();
```

Que te devuelve

> Mensaje = Hola, soy el hijo